# MySql Pivot - Navada Chart Style

Tags: mysql

**I have two tables in a MySql database.**

[image]

[image]

**I would like the query to pivot and return the data in a Nevada chart format - like this:**

[image]

**As the returns grows month to month, the return columns will increase (dynamic number of columns)**

**I have spent countless hours researching online for examples and everything I found does not produce the output I need.**

**I'm thinking it's not easy to achieve this in MySQL.**

**If anyone knows how to write a query to accomplish this and can share an example would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: You need in stored procedure with dynamic SQL.

Comment: What would this look like?